# Get resource file names as string array and bind it to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, globalization, resourcedictionary

I had to globalize my wpf application so I have all my language resource dictionaries placed in MyWPFApplication.Resources.Languages folder. I want to iterate through all the ResourceDictionaries that are there in the Languages folder and get their names in to String array so I can bind it to a combobox and use it to dynamically change languages at run time. Any neat way of doing this? or is there any better way of achieving it?

Comment: I am new to .NET programming. I used the following code 
ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            dictionary.Source = new Uri(@"/Resources/Languages/" + langName + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);

But it does not change languages globally but only in the current form

Comment: Please don't add code into comments as it is hard to see clearly... if you have something to add, please edit your *question* and add it to the end.